# Parsing a url link for a tag from a list of url links parsed from a saved html file. And saving it all in a csv ouput

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, mechanize, urlparse

How can I make a smooth transition from the Part 1 to Part 2 and to save the results in Part3? So far, I have not been able to parse a scraped url link unless i inserted it into Part 2 myself. Besides, I could not save the output results as the last url link overwrote all the other ones.

```
import urllib
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os, os.path
import urlparse
import re
import csv
```

Part 1:

```
path = '/Users/.../Desktop/parsing/1.html'

f = open(path,"r")
if f.mode == 'r':       
    contents = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content
search = soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'mf_oH mf_nobr mf_pRel'})
searchtext = str(search)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(searchtext)   

for tag in soup1.findAll('a', href = True):
    raw_url = tag['href'][:-7]
    url = urlparse.urlparse(raw_url)
    p = "http"+str(url.path)
```

Part 2:

```
for i in url:
    url = "A SCRAPED URL LINK FROM ABOVE"

    homepage = urllib.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(homepage)

    for tag in soup.findAll('a',attrs={'name':'g_my.main.right.gifts.link-send'}):
        searchtext = str(tag['href'])
        original = searchtext
        removed = original.replace("gifts?send=", "")
        print removed
```

Part 3

```
i = 0
for i in removed:
    f = open("1.csv", "a+")
    f.write(removed)
    i += 1
    f.close
```

Update 1.After the advice, I still get this: 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "page.py", line 31, in 
    homepage = urllib.urlopen(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 180, in open
    fullurl = unwrap(toBytes(fullurl))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1057, in unwrap
    url = url.strip()
AttributeError: 'ParseResult' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: You don't need to check the file mode when you've just opened the file yourself, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

In part 1, you keep overwriting `url` with a new URL. You should be using a list and append the URLs to that list:

```
urls = []
for tag in soup1.findAll('a', href = True):
    raw_url = tag['href'][:-7]
    url = urlparse.urlparse(raw_url)
    urls.append(url)
    p = "http"+str(url.path) # don't know what that's for, you're not using it later
```

Then, in part 2, you can iterate over `urls` directly. Again, `removed` shouldn't be overwritten with each iteration. Also, no need for the variable `original` - your searchtext won't be changed by a `replace` operation since it returns a new string and leaves the original alone:

```
removed_list = []
for url in urls:
    homepage = urllib.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(homepage)

    for tag in soup.findAll('a',attrs={'name':'g_my.main.right.gifts.link-send'}):
        searchtext = str(tag['href'])
        removed = searchtext.replace("gifts?send=", "")
        print removed
        removed_list.append(removed)
```

Then, in part 3, you don't have to open and close the file for each line you're outputting. In fact, you weren't even closing it properly because you didn't *call*  the `close()` method. The proper way is using the [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) anyway:

```
with open("1.csv", "w") as outfile:
    for item in removed_list:
        outfile.write(item + "\n")
```

Although I don't see how this is a CSV file (only one item per line?)...

Comment: url = p. I replaced 'p' with "A SCRAPED URL LINK FROM ABOVE"

Comment: You are right. I would prefer csv with one item per line.

Comment: Oh well, then it's not really a comma-separated file, is it?